# How to retrieve one or more phone numbers of one contact from android phone?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to retrieve multiple numbers from one contacts which is already saved to phone.
So how to read numbers of one contact programmatically in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created my own custom class for doing this , it may help you :

```
package com.android.addressbook.result;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;


public class Contact {

    String id = "";
    String displayName = "";
    String dateOfBirth = "";
    String dateOfAnniversary = "";
    String nickName = "";
    String note = "";
    Bitmap image = null;

    HashMap<Integer, String> emails;
    HashMap<Integer, String> phones;
    HashMap<Integer, Address> addresses;
    HashMap<Integer, Organization> organizations;
    HashMap<Integer, String> im;





    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }


    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }


    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }


    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }


    public String getDateOfAnniversary() {
        return dateOfAnniversary;
    }


    public void setDateOfAnniversary(String dateOfAnniversary) {
        this.dateOfAnniversary = dateOfAnniversary;
    }


    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }


    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }


    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }


    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }


    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }


    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


    public HashMap<Integer, String> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }


    public void setEmails(HashMap<Integer, String> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }


    public HashMap<Integer, String> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }


    public void setPhones(HashMap<Integer, String> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }


    public HashMap<Integer, Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }


    public void setAddresses(HashMap<Integer, Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }


    public HashMap<Integer, Organization> getOrganizations() {
        return organizations;
    }


    public void setOrganizations(HashMap<Integer, Organization> organizations) {
        this.organizations = organizations;
    }


    public HashMap<Integer, String> getIm() {
        return im;
    }


    public void setIm(HashMap<Integer, String> im) {
        this.im = im;
    }






    /******************************************************************************************/
    static class Address {

        private String postBox = "";
        private String street = "";
        private String city = "";
        private String state = "";
        private String postalCode = "";
        private String country = "";
        private String neighborhood = "";

        public String getPostBox() {
            return postBox;
        }

        public void setPostBox(String postBox) {
            this.postBox = postBox;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public String getPostalCode() {
            return postalCode;
        }

        public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
            this.postalCode = postalCode;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getNeighborhood() {
            return neighborhood;
        }

        public void setNeighborhood(String neighborhood) {
            this.neighborhood = neighborhood;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Address [postBox=" + postBox + "\n street=" + street
                    + "\n city=" + city + "\n state=" + state + "\n postalCode="
                    + postalCode + "\n country=" + country + "\n neighborhood="
                    + neighborhood + "]";
        }
    }

    /**********************************/
    static class Organization {
        private String company = "";
        private String jobTitle = "";

        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public void setCompany(String company) {
            this.company = company;
        }

        public String getJobTitle() {
            return jobTitle;
        }

        public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
            this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Organization [company=" + company + "\n jobTitle="
                    + jobTitle + "]";
        }
    }

    /**********************************/
    public static class Email_TYPE {
        // Email Type
        public static final int HOME = 1;
        public static final int WORK = 2;
        public static final int OTHER = 3;
        public static final int MOBILE = 4;
    }

    /**********************************/
    public static class PHONE_TYPE {
        // / Phone Type
        public static final int HOME = 1;
        public static final int MOBILE = 2;
        public static final int WORK = 3;
        public static final int FAX_WORK = 4;
        public static final int FAX_HOME = 5;
        public static final int PAGER = 6;
        public static final int OTHER = 7;
    }

    /**********************************/
    public static class ADDRESS_TYPE {
        // / Address Type
        public static final int HOME = 1;
        public static final int WORK = 2;
        public static final int OTHER = 3;
    }

    /**********************************/
    public static class ORGANIZATION_TYPE {
        // / Organization Type
        public static final int WORK = 2;
        public static final int OTHER = 3;
    }


    /**********************************/
    public static class IM_TYPE {
        public static final int CUSTOM = -1;
        public static final int AIM = 0;
        public static final int MSN = 1;
        public static final int YAHOO = 2;
        public static final int SKYPE = 3;
        public static final int QQ = 4;
        public static final int GOOGLE_TALK = 5;
        public static final int ICQ = 6;
        public static final int JABBER = 7;
        public static final int NETMEETING = 8;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [id=" + id + "\n displayName=" + displayName
                + "\n dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth + "\n dateOfAnniversary="
                + dateOfAnniversary + "\n nickName=" + nickName + "\n note="
                + note + "\n image=" + image + "\n emails=" + emails
                + "\n phones=" + phones + "\n addresses=" + addresses
                + "\n organizations=" + organizations + "\n im=" + im + "]";
    }

}
```

PhoneContact.java

```
package com.android.addressbook.result;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import com.android.addressbook.result.Contact.Address;
import com.android.addressbook.result.Contact.Organization;


public class PhoneContact {

    ContentResolver cr;
    List<Contact> contactList;
    Context context;

    public PhoneContact(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        cr = context.getContentResolver();
        contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        readContacts();
    }

    public void readContacts() {

        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();

                    // Get contact id (id)
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    contact.setId(id);

                    // Get contact name (displayName)
                    String displayName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    contact.setDisplayName(displayName);

                    // Get BirthDay (dateOfBirth)
                    Uri URI_DOB = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_DOB = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ? AND "
                                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                            + " = ? AND "
                                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE
                                            + "="
                                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_DOB = new String[] {
                                            id,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currDOB = cr.query(URI_DOB, null, SELECTION_DOB,SELECTION_ARRAY_DOB, null);
                    int indexDob = currDOB.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE);
                    if (currDOB.moveToNext()) {
                        String dobStr = currDOB.getString(indexDob);
                        contact.setDateOfBirth(dobStr);
                    }
                    currDOB.close();





                    // Get Anniversary (dateOfAnniversary)
                    Uri URI_DOA = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_DOA = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ? AND "
                                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                            + " = ? AND "
                                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE
                                            + "="
                                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_ANNIVERSARY;
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_DOA = new String[] {
                                            id,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currDOA = cr.query(URI_DOA, null, SELECTION_DOA,SELECTION_ARRAY_DOA, null);
                    int indexDoa = currDOA.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE);
                    if (currDOA.moveToNext()) {
                        String doaStr = currDOA.getString(indexDoa);
                        contact.setDateOfAnniversary(doaStr);
                    }
                    currDOA.close();





                    // Get Nick Nmae(nickName)
                    Uri URI_NICK_NAME = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_NICK_NAME = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ? AND "
                                                + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                                + " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_NICK_NAME = new String[] {
                                                id,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currNickName = cr.query(URI_NICK_NAME, null,
                                                SELECTION_NICK_NAME, SELECTION_ARRAY_NICK_NAME,
                                                null);

                    int indexNickName = currNickName.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME);
                    if (currNickName.moveToNext()) {
                        String nickNameStr = currNickName
                                .getString(indexNickName);
                        contact.setNickName(nickNameStr);
                    }
                    currNickName.close();





                    // GetNote(note)
                    Uri URI_NOTE = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_NOTE = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                            + " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_NOTE = new String[] {
                                            id,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currNote = cr.query(URI_NOTE, null, SELECTION_NOTE,SELECTION_ARRAY_NOTE, null);
                    int indexNote = currNote.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE);
                    if (currNote.moveToNext()) {
                        String noteStr = currNote.getString(indexNote);
                        contact.setNote(noteStr);
                    }
                    currNote.close();






                    // Get User Image (image)
                    Uri URI_PHOTO = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_PHOTO = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                                + " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_PHOTO = new String[] {
                                                id,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currPhoto = cr.query(URI_PHOTO, null,SELECTION_PHOTO, SELECTION_ARRAY_PHOTO, null);
                    int indexPhoto = currPhoto.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO);

                    while (currPhoto.moveToNext()) {

                        byte[] photoByte = currPhoto.getBlob(indexPhoto);

                        if (photoByte != null) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByte, 0, photoByte.length);

                            // Getting Caching directory
                            File cacheDirectory = context.getCacheDir();

                            // Temporary file to store the contact image
                            // File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath()
                            // + "/image_"+id+".png");
                            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath()+ "/image_.png");

                            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                            try {
                                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,fOutStream);

                                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                                fOutStream.flush();

                                // Close the FileOutputStream
                                fOutStream.close();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // String photoPath = tmpFile.getPath();
                            contact.setImage(bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                    currPhoto.close();



                    // Get Email and Type.... (<HashMap<Integer, String> emails)
                    Uri URI_EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_EMAIL = new String[] { id };

                    Cursor emailCur = cr.query(URI_EMAIL, null,SELECTION_EMAIL, SELECTION_ARRAY_EMAIL, null);
                    int indexEmail = emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
                    int indexEmailType = emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE);

                    if (emailCur.getCount() > 0) {

                        HashMap<Integer, String> emailMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

                        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                            // This would allow you get several email addresses,
                            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                            String emailStr = emailCur.getString(indexEmail);
                            String emailTypeStr = emailCur.getString(indexEmailType);
                            emailMap.put(Integer.parseInt(emailTypeStr),emailStr);
                        }
                        contact.setEmails(emailMap);
                    }
                    emailCur.close();





                    // Get Phone Number....(HashMap<Integer, String>phones)
                    Uri URI_PHONE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_PHONE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_PHONE = new String[] { id };

                    Cursor currPhone = cr.query(URI_PHONE, null,SELECTION_PHONE, SELECTION_ARRAY_PHONE, null);
                    int indexPhoneNo = currPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                    int indexPhoneType = currPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);

                    if (currPhone.getCount() > 0) {
                        HashMap<Integer, String> phoneMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                        while (currPhone.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNoStr = currPhone.getString(indexPhoneNo);
                            String phoneTypeStr = currPhone.getString(indexPhoneType);

                            phoneMap.put(Integer.parseInt(phoneTypeStr),phoneNoStr);
                        }
                        contact.setPhones(phoneMap);
                    }
                    currPhone.close();





                    // Get Postal Address....(HashMap<Integer, Address> addresses)
                    Uri URI_ADDRESS = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_ADDRESS = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                                + " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_ADDRESS = new String[] {
                                                id,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currAddr = cr.query(URI_ADDRESS, null,SELECTION_ADDRESS, SELECTION_ARRAY_ADDRESS, null);
                    int indexAddType = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE);
                    int indexStreet = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET);
                    int indexPOBox = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX);
                    int indexNeighbor = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD);
                    int indexCity = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY);
                    int indexRegion = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION);
                    int indexPostCode = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE);
                    int indexCountry = currAddr
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY);

                    if (currAddr.getCount() > 0) {
                        HashMap<Integer, Address> addressMap = new HashMap<Integer, Contact.Address>();
                        while (currAddr.moveToNext()) {

                            Contact.Address address = new Contact.Address();

                            String typeStr = currAddr.getString(indexAddType);

                            address.setStreet(currAddr.getString(indexStreet));
                            address.setNeighborhood(currAddr.getString(indexNeighbor));
                            address.setPostalCode(currAddr.getString(indexPostCode));
                            address.setPostBox(currAddr.getString(indexPOBox));
                            address.setCity(currAddr.getString(indexCity));
                            address.setState(currAddr.getString(indexRegion));
                            address.setCountry(currAddr.getString(indexCountry));

                            addressMap.put(Integer.parseInt(typeStr), address);
                        }
                        contact.setAddresses(addressMap);
                    }
                    currAddr.close();




                    // Get Organization (HashMap<Integer, Organization> organizations)
                    Uri URI_ORGNIZATION = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_ORGNIZATION = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                                    + " = ? AND "
                                                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                                    + " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_ORGNIZATION = new String[] {
                                                    id,
                                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currOrg = cr.query(URI_ORGNIZATION, null,
                                                    SELECTION_ORGNIZATION, SELECTION_ARRAY_ORGNIZATION,
                                                    null);
                    int indexOrgType = currOrg
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE);
                    int indexOrgName = currOrg
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA);
                    int indexOrgTitle = currOrg
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE);

                    if (currOrg.getCount() > 0) {
                        HashMap<Integer, Organization> orgMap = new HashMap<Integer, Contact.Organization>();
                        while (currOrg.moveToNext()) {

                            Contact.Organization organization = new Organization();

                            String orgTypeStr = currOrg.getString(indexOrgType);

                            organization.setCompany(currOrg.getString(indexOrgName));
                            organization.setJobTitle(currOrg.getString(indexOrgTitle));

                            orgMap.put(Integer.parseInt(orgTypeStr),organization);
                        }
                        contact.setOrganizations(orgMap);
                    }
                    currOrg.close();





                    // Get Instant Messenger..... (HashMap<Integer, String> im)
                    Uri URI_IM = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    String SELECTION_IM = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                            + " = ?";
                    String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_IM = new String[] {
                                            id,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                    Cursor currIM = cr.query(URI_IM, null, SELECTION_IM,SELECTION_ARRAY_IM, null);
                    int indexName = currIM
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA);
                    int indexType = currIM
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL);

                    if (currIM.getCount() > 0) {
                        HashMap<Integer, String> imMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                        while (currIM.moveToNext()) {
                            String imNameStr = currIM.getString(indexName);
                            String imTypeStr = currIM.getString(indexType);

                            imMap.put(Integer.parseInt(imTypeStr), imNameStr);
                        }
                        contact.setIm(imMap);
                    }
                    currIM.close();
                    /*****************************************/
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            }
        }
        cur.close();
    }

    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

and finally use this in your activity :

```
PhoneContact pCon = new PhoneContact(context);
        List<Contact> conList = pCon.getAllContacts();

        HashMap<Integer, String> phones = conList.get(0).getPhones();
        String home = phones.get(Contact.PHONE_TYPE.HOME);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the tutorial. i think it may help you. check once

[Working With Android Contacts](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Snippet can help you out

```
  String id , name;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

     String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

     Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,  null, null, null, sortOrder);



      if (cur.getCount() > 0) {


            while (cur.moveToNext()) {



                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                name = cur.getString( cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.i(tag, "Id is "+ id+"\t Name is"+name);

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){                      


                        Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,

                            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);


// this second loop will retrieve all the contact numbers for a paricular contact id 
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {


                // Do something with phones



                       int phNumber = pCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                       String phn = pCur.getString(phNumber);

                       Log.i("phn number",  phn);



                    } 

                    pCur.close();

                }

                }

    }
```